# pam_mkhomdir + nfs creates noboy:nogroup owned home dirs

Tags: debian, nfs4, pam-ldap

this is a strange issue I've been struggling with some time now.
I have a working ldap and authentication via pam on debian 8.
I have successful tested pam_mkhomedir and I got a home directory for the logged in user with ownership username:groupname.

In the second phase of the project I created an nfs (nfsv4) mount on /home/nfs
I want to put my home dirs there so I can share them across servers. The problem I face is when I use pam_mkhomdir to create the home dir it has ownership nobody:nogroup. 
If I create this manually logged in as an ldap user I get the correct ownership username:groupname so I am fairly sure nfs can deal with the ldap usernames.

idmap is configured to use nsswitch and

```
id ldapuser
```

returns the same info on both the nfs client and server. Also ldap login works on both of them

does anyone have an idea as to why pam_mkhomdir would default to nobody:nogroup while nfs works with ldap users?

Comment: http://www.softpanorama.org/Net/Application_layer/NFS/Troubleshooting/nfsv4_mounts_files_as_nobody.shtml

Comment: Sadly this did not help I double checked the domains in idmap.conf cleared the nfsidmap cache but to no avail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

pam_mkhomedir is running with root privileges and the NFS share is probably not exported with the `no_root_squash` option, so the root user gets mapped to NFS nobody.

Comment: This indeed solved it. So the reason that the ldap user could do this and pam could not was basically because the ldap user was not root?

Comment: Yes, the `root_squash` exportfs option maps requests from uid/gid 0 to the anonymous uid/gid, but only for the uid 0,  for all other users the regular file system permissions apply